# How to grep for two variables in two different line?

Tags: perl, grep

I have a situation where i need to find a line in a file which contains certain keyword for example ,below i am looking for foo and foobar in a file:

```
 Line 1 Line 1
 Line 2 foo Line 2
 Line 3 foobar Line 3
 Line 4 Line 4
 etc
```

and have to print both line after adding few strings.
chances are that foobar may not exist but foo will always exist.

And they will only exist once.

After finding foo and foobar necessary transition need to be done.

```
grep m%foo%, @lines;
grep m%foobar%,@lines;
```

Comment: Why not just grep for `foobar` if it exists only once?

Comment: i need to grep for foo if its there then do some manipulation and add to output, if foobar is also  present then its added to the output as well.

Comment: You said in your question that "foo" is always there, so really what merlin2011 mentioned is completely valid. All you need to check for is foobar...

Comment: This is a dreadful question. You need to "find a line", so *one* line, and you are looking for `foo` (and? or?) `foobar` and you have to "print both line", so now there are *two*. "`foo` will always exist" but your example shows lines without either `foo` or `foobar`. Any line that contains `foobar` clearly also contains `foo`. You must explain yourself better, and I suggest that you use real data and show clearly what result you want. You appear to be writing code before it is clear in your head what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please don't use percent `%` as the delimiter for *match* `m//`. A slash `/` is the default and the most familiar, and you should also omit the `m`, like `grep /foo/, @lines`

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you are doing with the result, although you can grab both `foo` and `foobar`:

```
grep -noE "foo\w*"
```

If you want to be specific:

```
grep -noE "foo|foobar"
```

**Output:**

```
2:foo
3:foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

your grep commands work well:

```
my @lines = split ("\n", <<'END');
Line 1 Line 1
 Line 2 foo Line 2
 Line 3 foobar Line 3
 Line 4 Line 4
END

my ($foo) = grep m%foo%, @lines;
my ($foobar) = grep m%foobar%,@lines;

my $res = lc $foo;
$res .= lc $foobar if defined $foobar;
print "$res\n";
```

IMHO doing a grep to find the needed lines, then manipulating these lines is a bad approach. The general pattern should be to iterate over the lines, to match a regexp to collect the needed data and finally to format your output. This code pattern works is ideal for 90% of file parsers.

```
my ($f1, $f2, $fb1, $fb2);
for my $line (@lines) {
    if ($line =~ m/(\d+) foo Line (\d+)/) {
        $f1 = $1;
        $f2 = $2;
    } elsif ($line =~ m/(\d+) foobar Line (\d+)/) {
        $fb1 = $1;
        $fb2 = $2;
    }
}

if (defined $fb1) {
    print "foo and foobar: $f1 $f2 $fb1 $fb2\n";
} else {
    print "Only foo $f1 $f2\n";
}
```